# Includes only working on dev server

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have the following code in a php/html file:

```
<?php
    include('sample.php');
    include_once('foo.php');
    include('bar.php');
?>
```

On my dev server (php's built-in server), everything is working fine, on the production server (apache2) though I get a blank page when accessing the file.
The only way to get to the actual page is by removing all 3 includes, removing a single one or two of them does not resolve the problem. In the included files I do include files, which might get loaded more than once with include_once. Apart from that I have no glue why there is an error since everything is working on my dev server and some of the included files work well in other parts of the app.

Comment: A blank page usually means there's a 500 internal server error occurring. Are there any messages in Apache's error logs?

Comment: You probably know this already, but you have to make sure that all the included files, and all the files included by the included files, are in exactly the same directory structure on your production server. That's one possible reason it isn't working, but there are many other possibilities. Anything in any of the included files could be causing it due to version or configuration differences. It's good that you're getting a blank page, because errors shouldn't be sent to the browser on your prod server, but you should be able to find the real error in your web server logs.

Comment: Without that information, though, we have no way of answering this for you, unfortunately. There are too many possible causes for a WSOD.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I, unfortunately, do not have access to the log files atm

Comment: Include is not a function, there is no need for the `()` because `include 'sample.php';` will work just fine.  Also check your casing, if you use windows for development, and linux for deployment, linux is case sensitive windows is not.  On windows `sample.php` is the same as `Sample.php` on LInux it is not.

Comment: @Maaaaa then enable error reporting as the very first thing you do before the includes: `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` should do it for this. That should make the error message(s) appear on screen for you.

Comment: It's potentially a difference between the `include_path` ini setting on the two servers, but that's fairly rare these days.

Comment: you could try `__DIR__.'/bar.php';`

Comment: another thing to look for in casing is this `foo.php` vs `foo.PHP` both work on windows but only one works on Linux, which one depends on the file name.  if you file is `foo.PHP` and you include `foo.php` it will work on windows and not Linux.  Because, again, linux is case sensitive.

Comment: It doesn't have to be casing or a problem with your include path, it could be that you're trying to use a function from an extension that isn't installed on your production server. The error message will tell you that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I use Linux on both machines

Comment: @Maaaaa - ok, it's the first thing I think of when someone says it works on this but not on that.  It's usually an environment thing, not a problem with the code - per say

Answer (score 1):

It is probable that the configuration of `include_path` on your dev server contains `.`, which means: *if file is included with relative path, try to find it in the current directory*. This setting is probably not present on the prod server (see for yourself with `phpinfo()`).